# Detect IE6 with Jquery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, browser

I am trying to establish how to detect the IE browser in jQuery 1.3.X - now before you all write "its deprecated in 1.3.x!" - I know this. I have this code

```
if (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version == "6.0") {
  alert ("This is less than IE7");
} else {
  alert ("This is greater than IE7");
}
```

When running it in IE8 - IE6 (quirks), IE7 and IE8 all return "less than IE7". Can anyone help me determine this correctly **using jquery** ? (please note: **using jquery**)

*Edit:  I am trying to basically change the position element in IE6 to "absolute" and use "fixed" for IE7 and IE8. Not sure how to do this without detecting browser?*

Edit2: Seems something like this might work?

```
   if ((window.XMLHttpRequest == undefined) && (ActiveXObject != undefined)) {
        alert ("This is not IE6");
       } else {
        alert ("This is greater than IE6"); 
       }
```

Comment: What's your ultimate goal here? The whole point of jQuery is to abstract this sort of thing. It's better to check for a feature than for a particular browser.

Comment: hey draemon - i am trying to basically change the position element in IE6 to "absolute" and use "fixed" for IE7 and IE8. Not sure how to do this without detecting browser?

Comment: I provided a method that relies on object detection.

Comment: I'm about to edit your code to put a closing brace before the else block.  This wasn't the issue was it?

Comment: hey thanks scunliffe. nah, sorry just missed pasting apologies. it doesnt work in IE anymore this code - so just hoping someone can tell me how to resolve this ? :)

Comment: You aren't doing anything like running multiple versions of Internet Explorer on the same OS, are you?

Comment: hey chung - nah. just using IE8 to test and when I rotate through the Developer tools quirks, iE7 and ie8 - always get "less than ie7" ?

Comment: This CSS would give IE6 the specific property that you were looking for:

* html #thing {position: absolute;}
#thing {position: fixed;}

If this is what you're looking for, you may want to re-word your question and post this as an answer.

Comment: Edit2's `if(window.XMLHttpRequest == undefined)...` gives a false-positive for IE 8 users that turn off “Enable native XMLHTTP support” option in their advanced settings.

Answer (score 2):

you can always do this sort of thing with html or css...why do it with jquery?

Comment: He's talking about conditional comments or css hacks by the way. Conditional comments are the way to go here.

Comment: More info on condtional comments here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 0):

the method in the update #2 above, i.e. checking for the `XMLHttpRequest` member on the window, can fail in cases where some other library has polyfilled support. You're best bet is going to be to use conditional comments, [this page](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/detect-ie-in-js-using-conditional-comments/) has an excellent explanation.

hope that helps! cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 7) {
  alert('This is less than IE7');  // just alerting what you said in question
} else {
  alert('Better than IE6'); // What if I'm not IE?
}
```